# Keep props updated with programatically generated components

Tags: vue.js, components

Imagine an empty virtual bulletin board where an unknown number of virtual notes will be placed. The board is the parent component and the note is the child.

When I click the board a new note appears on the board. When I move the mouse the note should follow the mouse cursor (weird UI I know, but I'm simplifying for the sake of this post).

I'm generating a new note by instancing it and then adding it to the dom like this:

```
  let NoteClass = Vue.extend(Note);
  let note = new NoteClass({
    propsData: { x: this.clientX, y: this.clientY },
  });
  note.$mount();
  this.$refs.board.appendChild(note.$el);
```

Notice the mouse x/y is passed to the note via props. This causes the note to appear at the position of the mouse cursor when I click. Great.

However, once the Note is instanced it no longer updates the x/y props. The Note does not continuously read the position of the mouse cursor from its parent.

Here's the full code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-wiles-pru1y?file=/src/App.vue

For comparison, check out this version where the Note is NOT generated in code. A single note is placed the typical way. It follows the cursor just fine:

https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-tree-xnthc?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: *The Note does not continuously read the position of the mouse cursor from its parent* ...yes, because it has no parent. Any reason why you instantiating child components like this instead of using standard Vue "data-driven" way ?

Comment: Can you elaborate? How would you go about it?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Component

Answer (score 0):

I found a way better solution thanks to Michal Levý's comment -- the data driven way:

```
<template>
    <div ref="board" class="board" @click.self="onClick" @mousemove.prevent="drag"> 
        <Note v-for="(note, key) in notes" :key="key" :x="clientX" :y="clientY"></Note>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Note from '@/components/Note.vue';

export default {
  name: 'Board',
  data() {
    return {
      clientX: 0,
      clientY: 0,
      notes: []
    }
  },
  components: {
    Note
  },
  methods: {
    onClick() {
      this.notes.push({});
    },
    drag(event) {
      this.clientX = event.clientX;
      this.clientY = event.clientY;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```